PWA "No manifest detected" only on Android but works on every other platform
I am developing a Progressive Web App and when I tried to test it out on my Android phone, it didn't work as clicking on "Add to home screen" doesn't return the PWA installer UI but the shortcut installer. Strange thing is that the PWA installer does appear on desktop while iOS Safari renders it correctly as a PWA.
There is one thing worth noticing is when I debugged via DevTools devices (I basically connected my Android phone to my desktop to inspect the code), I found out this line always disappear on my Android Chrome client:
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

...which this line is basically what a PWA needs to be activated, thus the Applications tab in DevTools shows "No manifest detected", and I am seriously confused how it kept getting removed for absolute no reason.
I tried clearing cache to make sure the website is running the latest version, checking if it was manifest and service workers related issues, or maybe incorrect file paths defined, and even referenced to this question on StackOverflow.
Here is my partial code for <head> in index.html:
<!-- PWA support -->
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<!-- WebClip support -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png" />

Here is my code for the manifest.json:
{
  "short_name": "some short name",
  "name": "some long name",
  "description": "some desc",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/icon.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ],
  "id": "/someId",
  "start_url": "/someId",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}

